# What is a reasonable bound for integrating the standard normal distribution with a single tail?

Tags: statistics

This is a question I'm trying to figure out how to solve because my calculator does not allow me to evaluate improper integrals. I am trying to find the z that produces a small enough p to be negligible. In general I think I will need about 5 digits of accuracy maximum but I would also be interested in the general solution for some natural n. The problem boils down to solving this inequality:

Find the least value of $a$ for which:
$$\int_a^\infty \frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} < 10^{-n}$$

Any insights on how I might go about this? This function doesn't even have an elementary antiderivative so this looks like a pretty tricky problem.

Comment: Turn to an ordinary integral using $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty-\displaystyle\int_0^a$.

Comment: so then it turns into $1/2 - \int_0^a f(x)$ which actually I can evaluate directly. but for the sake of actually finding the value of a which is less than 10^(-n), how do you proceed?

Comment: Use your calculator. Dichotomic search or Newton's iterations...

Comment: You can also use the complementary [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) which is available in many numerical software packages (see e.g. `scipy.special.erfc` in scipy). See also numerical approximations in the linked wikipedia article. Finally, it is interesting to note that the task is doable for distributions other than normal using the [concentration inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality). Chernoff's bound is particularly useful since it bounds the tails by an expression exponential in the distance from the mean.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Not really allowed to use a computer though, otherwise this would be a non issue.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: preferably the *inverse* error function.

Answer (score 2):

Admitting that you know the error function, you are looking for $a$ such that
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right) < 10^{-n}$$that is to say
$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)> 1-2\times 10^{-n}$$

When $a$ is large
$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=1-e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi
   }}}{a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^3}\right)\right)$$ and then we search for $a$ such that
$$e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} <  \sqrt{2\pi}\, 10^{-n}\, a$$ The solution of the *equation* is given in terms of Lambert function
$$a=\sqrt{W\left(\frac{10^{2n}}{2\pi}\right)}$$

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
1 & 1.43165 &  1.28155 \\
 2 & 2.37533 &  2.32635 \\
 3 & 3.11528 &  3.09023 \\
 4 & 3.73464 &  3.71902 \\
 5 & 4.27575 &  4.26489 \\
 6 & 4.76151 &  4.75342 \\
 7 & 5.20565 &  5.19934 \\
 8 & 5.61710 &  5.61200 \\
 9 & 6.00204 &  5.99781 \\
 10 & 6.36492 &  6.36134 \\
 11 & 6.70910 &  6.70602 \\
 12 & 7.03717 &  7.03449 \\
 13 & 7.35116 &  7.34882 \\
 14 & 7.65274 &  7.65056 \\
 15 & 7.94324 &  7.94324
\end{array}
\right)$$

Playing with the inverse error function, we could also have, as an *approximation*,

$$a=\sqrt{\log \left(\frac{2}{\pi  t^2}\right)-\log \left(\log \left(\frac{2}{\pi 
   t^2}\right)\right)}\quad \text{where} \qquad t=2\times 10^{-n}$$ which looks to be slightly better.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 1.32266 &  1.28155 \\
 2 & 2.31834 &  2.32635 \\
 3 & 3.08133 &  3.09023 \\
 4 & 3.71139 &  3.71902 \\
 5 & 4.25847 &  4.26489 \\
 6 & 4.74795 &  4.75342 \\
 7 & 5.19461 &  5.19934 \\
 8 & 5.60785 &  5.61200 \\
 9 & 5.99413 &  5.99781 \\
 10 & 6.35805 &  6.36134 \\
 11 & 6.70305 &  6.70602 \\
 12 & 7.03178 &  7.03449 \\
 13 & 7.34632 &  7.34882 \\
 14 & 7.64835 &  7.65056 \\
 15 & 7.93923 &  7.94324
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, if you need better, I think that the only solution would be given by a couple of iterations of Newton method.